# Error cordova build android

Tags: android, cordova

When I use the command:

```
cordova build android
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\CEN\APP_MOVIL\CENAPP>cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_80
Reading build config file: C:\CEN\APP_MOVIL\CENAPP\build.json

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
               > Remote host closed connection during handshake
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
            >
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.481 secs
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
               > Connection reset

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
               > Remote host closed connection during handshake
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
               > Connection reset

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use https://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: `3.1.4` is the current version, not `2.1.0`. and without the `build.json` nor the `build.gradle`, it is impossible to tell for certain what is wrong; most likely you're having the wrong repositories for the `buildscript`.